# Using Orange3 to predict image class

Tags: image-classification, orange

I used logistic regression to classify 3 classes of images: cars, dogs, cows. The accuracy is 100%, perfectly separated in clusters (scatter plots).
When I try to use the learner to predict 3 images (1 dog, 1 car, 1 cow), the predictor simply assign the probability of 1/3 to each image. How can I fix it?

[image: orange3 flows]

Comment: Is there any way to attach your ows file to your question? Also, the input data set would be helpful.

Comment: this link contains ows and input data http://jmp.sh/i5dJCZB

Answer (score 1):

It means that the model you are using fails at classifying the images. Logistic regression may not be the good one for your classification. Try using another model.